# Something is overriding style.css, likely not cache issue

Tags: php, html, css

I know next to nothing about coding but I'm eager to learn. But unfortunately I think I messed something up. For instance the padding above and below the logo on my site (www.reportglobe.com) were removed and worked as I wanted it to, however now it's back to it's original format.

Similarly, the styling I provided the pagination buttons on this page (http://reportglobe.com/entertainment/isaiah-richards-tika-sumpter/) have reverted to their original color.

I had some social media icons, but putting this wouldn't make them disappear:

```
.entry-social {
    display: none;
}
```

So I was forced to just delete the code for the icons directly from content-single.php

I was told all of this might all be due to something as mundane as a missing curly bracket in my style.css file but I can't find anything along those lines. I tried deleting all my plugins and that was no help either. I don't believe its a cache issue, but as I'm new to this I can't be too sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: wordpress - its a nightmere

Comment: using jquery `$(".entry-social").hide();` and try to validate your css online

Comment: Use the browser dev tools to look at what styles are being applied to an element. I use Firebug in Firefox it helps a ton. Also `display: none !important;` would work. It sound like you are using a third party library or widget that maybe dynamically loading other css files.

Comment: `display: none !important;` - that might work. It stops things from over writing it, also sometimes you may have to give the server a few mins to update CSS cos it does cache usually

Comment: Thanks for the tips regarding removing social media icons. Unfortunately, it's not working. I suspect it all has to do with the style.css override. I'm not sure how to use browser dev tools. But I'll figure it out through the almighty google and see if that helps.

Comment: Can you please specifically point the problems you have in your page? because about the top padding/margin of the logo I can see you have `margin-top: 15px;` in this class `#header .logo` or about the `.entry-social` class, I can not find and element with this class name in the page you provided in your post. Please be more clear about your problems so we can help...

Comment: For the header logo I've used the following code for the past month and it has worked:

`.logo-wrap .inner-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}`

Which is what I still see on style.css, but when checking the elements, it appears as 25px all of a sudden for some reason. Clearing the cache or deleting all the plugins didn't help. Similarly, the alterations to the `.entry-social` class from the style.css worked for a few days and all of a sudden it has reverted to the original code when checking the elements, but my changes are there in the style.css file.

Comment: Sorry, that should say it appears as **20px** all of a sudden when checking the elements. In summary: my changes are still there in style.css and the changes worked for a month with these codes. Then all of a sudden my original codes are appearing on the pages (and are what you see when you look up elements) and style.css is being overwritten.

Comment: Ehm... you're not using **style.css**. You're using **wp-content/cache/minify/5265b.css**, which does contain `.logo-wrap .inner-wrap{overflow:hidden;margin-bottom:20px}`.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much. At the risk of sounding like a complete idiot. How do you figure out what file the page is using (so I can look it up and not look like a complete idiot again)? And secondly, I assume this is due to caching, how do I fix it? Purging all the caching or deleting the caching plugin isn't helping. Thanks a bunch everyone. I'd like to use style.css instead of what it is currently using.

Comment: To see what css (and other) files are being used, just look at the page source in the browser. Now what causes the system to serve up a minified version of what is obviously an older css file, I can't say. I'm not that familiar with WordPress, sorry. Are there libraries, plugins etc that you can configure? Is it using LESS, SCSS etc? Did any of those settings change recently?